# Shebang command to call script from existing script - Python

Tags: python-2.7, os.system, shebang

I am running a python script on my raspberry pi, at the end of which I want to call a second python script in the same directory. I call it using the `os.system()` command as shown in the code snippet below but get import errors. I understand this is because the system interprets the script name as a shell command and needs to be told to run it using python, using the shebang line at the beginning of my second script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

However doing so does not solve the errors

Here is the ending snippet from the first script:

```
# Time to Predict E
  end3 = time.time()
  prediction_time = end3-start3
  print ("\nPrediction time: ", prediction_time, "seconds")

  i = i+1
  print (i) 



script = '/home/pi/piNN/exampleScript.py'
os.system('"' + script + '"')
```

and here is the beginning of my second script:

```
'#!usr/bin/env python'

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
#from picamera import PiCamera


import argparse
import sys
import time

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import PIL.Image as Image
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What are the actual import errors that you get when you run your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not posted the actual errors that you get when you run your code, this is my best guess. First, ensure that `exampleScript.py` is executable:

```
chmod +x /home/pi/piNN/exampleScript.py
```

Second, add a missing leading slash to the shebang in `exampleScript.py`, i.e. change

```
'#!usr/bin/env python'
```

to

```
'#!/usr/bin/env python'
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup that you have here is not ideal.

Consider simply importing your other script (make sure they are in the same directory). Importing it will result in the execution of all executable python code inside the script that is not wrapped in `if __name__ == "__main__":`. While on the topic, should you need to safeguard some code from being executed, place it in there.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 python file a.py and b.py and I set execute permission for b.py with.

```
chmod a+x b.py
```

Below is my sample:
a.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'Script a'
import os
script = './b.py'
os.system('"' + script + '"')
```

b.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'Script b'
```

Execute "python a.py", the result is:

```
Script a
Script b
```